# ACCOUNT_LACKS_PERMISSIONS createRecipientView

Tags: docusignapi

I use the createRecipientView interface to return {
  "errorCode": "ACCOUNT_LACKS_PERMISSIONS",
  "message": "This Account lacks sufficient permissions. In-Session permission required when specifying a captive recipient."
}

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

A search reveals this [link](https://help.lever.co/hc/en-us/articles/207932586-How-do-I-resolve-this-DocuSign-in-session-error-message-), which says:

> To successfully integrate DocuSign with [our service], please contact your
>   DocuSign account manager with this exact language:
>
> **We are receiving the error “This Account lacks sufficient permissions.
>   In-Session Permission is required when specifying a captive
>   recipient.” This error is known to be associated with In-Session
>   signing not being enabled on the account. In order to send documents
>   using [our] integration with DocuSign, I would like to ask you to
>   please set the In-Session signing to "enabled" in the Admin Console
>   and in Account Plan Editor.**